# highlight search in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, search, mobile, highlight

How can I highlight the words that are searched in jquery mobile? I'm using collapsed list with data-filter="true" and it works great with the search but there is a lot of text and for better user experience the searched words should be highlighted.

I've tried to implent these jquery plugins (not jquery mobile) but it didn't work:

http://www.jquery.info/spip.php?article50

http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/833/on-page-text-highlighting-Search-with-jQuery.html

I haven't found a solution for this anywhere on stackoverflow or the web so now I'm asking in hope of getting some help here.

The code I'm using right now is this:

```
    <div data-role="page" id="test"><p></p>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b" data-filter="true">
    
  <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false">
                                    <h2>Look here</h2>                          
                                        <li>
                                        <div dara-role="content">
                                        here is alot o text. This is searchable but should turn into yellow. </div>
                                        </li></div>
                                        
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false">
                                    <h2>Look here to</h2>                           
                                        <li><div data-role="content">
                                          More text.
                                        </div>
                                        </li></div> </ul>
```